# Monax Contract Nodejs Invocation Example

Tags: eris-industries, monax

I have setup a Monax development private chain environment using on Ubuntu 16.04. Now looking for an example of how to invoke the Smart Contract deployed on Monax chain. If you could direct a proper example in this regard will be quite helpful.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at this demo application. It shows the commands to deploy smart contracts to a Monax (Burrow) chain (`monax pkgs do ...`) and also contains a NodeJS app to interact with them.

https://github.com/monax/hello-doug

Comment: But this one says depreciated

Comment: It is still viable for your purposes.

Comment: Oh that is really great then